# parsing nvarchar(max) data field in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a field with stings like 'marketplace-used-new-ebook-rental_new-rental_used' where 'rental_new' is one piece and so on. This is all of the possible elements in the sting but they can be in any order and contain one or more pieces. How do I break this up so I can account for all the different combinations? I also cannot create functions on this database.

Comment: what vendor and version of sql ?

Comment: SSMS 2014 sql version 12.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have three options really

1. Do the work at the application layer
2. Write a cursor to do it
3. Use XML to do it

the below example is for XML

Note: XML can only be used if you can guarantee that your input string does not contain any XML characters. One string with <, > or & and the query will fail.

```
SELECT distinct a.split_me 
FROM
 (
   SELECT cast('<X>'+replace('marketplace-used-new-ebook-rental_new-
          rental_used','-','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xml_convert 
 )xml_data
 CROSS APPLY
 ( 
     SELECT fdata.D.value('.','nvarchar(50)') as split_me 
     FROM xml_data.xml_convert.nodes('X') as fdata(D)
 ) a
```

SQL server 2016 has a built in function to break out data, but until then it is one of those three options.